# Is there any way to trace a facebook page owner IP?

Tags: ip, facebook

I am in a country which limits political opinions I need to create a facebook page but first I need to know is there any way that someone can trace my IP ? In other words could I be busted ? Please I need a trusted answer from an expert , my country has got hackers for this kind of stuff and thank you all , and if answer is yes , is there anyway to get hidden  ?

Comment: Since stackexchange websties apparently don't use https I'd be more worried about using the phrase `I am in a country which limits political opinions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query Facebook pages directly, I think they'd have to request the info from Facebook, Inc. directly. But there are other methods a hacker could use (spyware or tracking through your ISP). In your case, I would not assume any method is safe from prying eyes.

I haven't had need to look into this very much, being from a different country that doesn't do these things, however the two methods that would be useful for avoiding tracking by third parties that I can think of would be using https wherever possible (there's plugins to do that), and use TOR, which intends to anonymize your behavior by routing your Internet traffic through several encrypted proxies. There are many other methods, but these are two things to try. [The EFF has a page that links to both options.](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Yes somebody can trace your IP address and there are many ways in which it can be done, it is not hard if you know what you are doing so yes you could be busted.

There are a few way to hide your presence on the net and as Ben Richards has stated one way is to use a Tor network, so have a look into that as a priority but remember that nothing is impossible.